# Mac OS X Sierra : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, xcode, macos, clang, linphone-sdk

I am trying to build a C source file based on Linphone in Mac OS X Sierra but getting the following error.

This is the link for the C source file. 
http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__basic__call__tutorials.html

Edited:

I am trying to compile the source code with this command

> clang -o tt tt.c -I/Users/softdev/Downloads/linphone-sdk-3.11.1-mac/include/

Error:

> > Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 
> >     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
> >     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried to change the target cpu but didn't work.

My system has XCode 8. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Edited: Complete Output

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_linphone_call_get_state", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_call_ref", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_call_unref", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_core_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_core_invite", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_core_iterate", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_core_new", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_linphone_core_terminate_call", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
  "_ms_usleep", referenced from:
      _main in tt-ca2045.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the target or the CPU. It's about you not linking with something you need to link with. The linker would have told you *what* symbols are missing, why don't you tell us that? Please edit your question to include the *full* error output.

Comment: Where are you getting your liblinphone library from?  The documentation you're referring to dates from 2010 (which might be before `x86_64` was even an option in Xcode).  I do see a much more recent version of liblinphone at https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited my question.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I have downloaded the binary from the below link. I don't want to use linphone. I just want to use the underlying liblinphone libraries in my custom software for Mac http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads

Comment: So you don't actually link with the library you want to use? Then I assume the undefined symbols are all functions from that library (since you still haven't included the full and complete error output)? You need to link with the actual library as well. Is there a file beginning with `lib` and ending with `.a` in the installation of the library? Pass the full path to that file when you build.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have added full error output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the sample code to compile using this:

```
clang -o hello hello.c -Ilinphone-sdk-3/include -Llinphone-sdk-3/lib -llinphone -lmediastreamer_base
```

Clang's `-I` parameter points to the where the header (.h) files live

And as for my additions, `-L` specifies the *path* for clang to get to where the lib files live.  In your case, it might live in `-L/Users/softdev/Downloads/linphone-sdk-3.11.1-mac/lib`

then `-l` specifies which dylibs you want to include (strip off the `lib` prefix and the `dylib` suffix).

Lastly, you need to add a missing line to the sample code you pointed to.  Add:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

after `signal.h`

Comment: Thanks It worked but I am getting ortp error now. I have tried with -lortp also. Error is > "ortp-error-Error in connect: No route to host". Any idea Micheal?

Comment: Now that you got things to compile, it sounds like a brand new problem. Look closely at the source code you pointed to.  I don't see an actual hostname in there (e.g. "stackoverflow.com" or "apple.com").

Comment: I am using the demo SIP uri mentioned in the tutorial there. https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Linux-MAC/